# Why is my database not creating a .db file in my working directory? I am using Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Pycharm Professional. I have a file named basic.py which contains my Models and and code to create the Models in a database. The code runs fine, it does not encounter any errors, however after running the code it does not create a .db file in my working directory. I cant find it at all even though i have used db.create_all(). What am I missing here? Thanks

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

print(os.getcwd())
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'sqlite:////site.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Puppy(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)

    to_owner = db.relationship("Owner", backref="puppy", uselist=False)
    to_toy = db.relationship("Toy", backref= "puppy", lazy = "dynamic")

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"This is {self.name}"



class Owner(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    pupid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("puppy.id"))

    def __init__(self, name, pup):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = pup


class Toy(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    pupid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("puppy.id"))

    def __init__(self, name, pup):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = pup

db.create_all()

john = Puppy("john")
jack = Puppy("jack")

print(john.name)
db.session.add_all([john, jack])
db.session.commit()
print(john.name)

print(Puppy.query.all())

john = Puppy.query.filter_by(name="john").first()
print(john)

owner1 = Owner("amr", john.id)


toy1 = Toy("ball", john.id)
toy2 = Toy("frisby", john.id)

db.session.add_all([owner1, toy1, toy2])
db.session.commit()

john = Puppy.query.filter_by(name="john").first()
print(john.name)
```

Comment: Hi, did that suggestion help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one too many `/` in your SQLite directory specification for your SQLAlchemy URI. Can you change the database URI to the following and see if this resolves your issue:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
```